# why the results of below two codes are different?

Tags: python, yield, finally

code1:

```
def af():
    a=65
    try:
       yield a

    finally:
        print('end')

print(af().next())
```

code2:

```
def af():
    a=65
    try:
       yield a

    finally:
        print('end')

g=af()
print(g.next())
```

---

the result of code1 is:

```
end
65
```

but the result of code2 is:

```
65
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In snippet 1, when Python executes

```
print(af().next())
```

it gets through

```
      af().next()
```

and then the generator object's reference count falls to 0. At this point, Python calls the generator's `close` method to force `finally` blocks and `__exit__` methods to run, so the `finally` block prints `end`.

*Then* the `print` part of `print(af().next())` runs and prints `65`.

---

In snippet 2, when Python executes

```
print(g.next())
```

the generator object is kept alive by the reference from the `g` variable, so the `finally` block doesn't run at this point, and Python prints `65`.

Then, during interpreter shutdown, the generator's refcount falls to 0, and `close` triggers the `finally` block, which prints `end`. This is not guaranteed to happen - Python does not guarantee that objects alive at interpreter shutdown will have their destructors called - but it happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of when the generator itself is cleaned up. When you don't save a reference to the generator, as soon as the last reference goes out of scope (at least on CPython, the "reference" interpreter, which is apropos here, since it's reference counted), the generator is cleaned up, which immediately raises `GeneratorExit` in the body of the generator, causing it to reach the `finally` block and print.

In your first example, `print(af().next())` the moment `next` returns, there are no longer any living references to the generator, so it's cleaned up, causing the `finally` block to execute immediately (`print` hasn't been called yet, we're still getting the arguments to pass to it).

In your second example, you saved a reference to the generator in `g`, so until `g` is destroyed (on program exit in this case), the generator remains ready to resume (it would resume following the `yield`). The `print` finishes, then the program goes through end of program cleanup and the `finally` block executes.

Note that the cleanup of the globals like this isn't guaranteed; CPython 2.7 happens to set all globals to `None` on shutdown, which gets you this behavior, but it's not contractual; you'd want to explicitly run out or `close` the generator (via `contextlib.closing` if needed) to ensure it's really cleaned up.